# Init T generic object with values

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have this method:

```
 public long getConfigVal<T>( int key, ref T sResultType) where T : class{}
```

My method have to insert the same configurations value like the e sResultType type .( if sResultType is int , I  will insert int value ,if sResultType is string, I will insert string value)

this code dont compile but help me to explain myself:

```
if (sResultType is string)
    sResultType= "abc";
if (sResultType is int)
    sResultType= 123;
```

Does something have idea?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with specific inputs and expected outputs based on those inputs.

Comment: Whenever you have to know the exact type in generic code you should stop and think if that code should really be generic.

Comment: Yes yes, you are so quick response!! I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people will say you shouldn't do it like that, and they are right. But if you really want to, you need to perform cast through `object`:

```
public static long getConfigVal<T>(int key, ref T sResultType) where T : class {
    if (sResultType is string) {
        sResultType = (T)(object)"test";
    }
    if (sResultType is int)
        sResultType = (T) (object) 123;
    ...
}
```

But better reconsider your design to avoid treating generic type in non-generic way.